# Passing Json data to handsontable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json.net, handsontable

I am trying to get data from my database and display it in handsontable using Json. Here is the code I have written so far. Can anyone guide me about how tosolve this problem.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<SupplierTypeDto> supplierType = new List<SupplierTypeDto>();
            var apiResponse = Post<List<SupplierTypeDto>>("api/SupplierType/SuppliersType", null);

            if (apiResponse != null)
            {
                if (apiResponse.Success)
                {
                    supplierType = apiResponse.Data;
                    // ShowSuccessMesage(string.Format(ResponseMessages.DATA_Load_Success, "Customers"));
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ShowErrorMesage(ResponseMessages.API_NoResponse);
            }

            return Json(supplierType,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


 The code added below has data part and I want that data from Json so I can show it in Index file.

      <script>
            const data = [
  ['', 'Tesla', 'Volvo', 'Toyota', 'Ford'],
  ['2019', 10, 11, 12, 13],
  ['2020', 20, 11, 14, 13],
  ['2021', 30, 15, 12, 13]
];

const container = document.getElementById('example');
const hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: data,
    rowHeaders: true,
  licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
  colHeaders: true
});
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have line

> const container = document.getElementById('example');

but non html was provided in example. So probably you just need to add

> `<div id="example"></div>`

to your html code

Comment: I have added that div to my html code and it is displaying that array data but the problem is I the data I want is from data base through Json so I can pass it to handsontable. The data array above is just an example.